# Keep changing value on realtime on twig with Hinclude.js on Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, asynchronous, real-time

I followed these[SymfonyDoc](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/hinclude.html)[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S28anpB1E0Ahttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S28anpB1E0A),
and succeeded create a controller and a twig which has asynchronous contents by rendering the controller... but it's only onetime changing.

Is there possible way to show value which keep changing on realtime on twig by using Hinclude.js on Symfony.

Comment: Hinclude.js does not enable real-time content updates. You would need to implement a separate solution that utilizes [HTTP WebSockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API), Polling (Ajax/XMLHttpRequest), or HTTP 2.0 SSE ([Mercure protocol](https://symfony.com/doc/current/mercure.html)) for updating the content dynamically with what appears as "real-time" changes.

Comment: @WillB. thank you so much I will figure it out with ajax

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this may work if you set the Cache-Control headers (https://odino.org/scaling-through-hinclude/).

Try this:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    $response = new Response($this->renderView('index.html.twig', []), 200);

    $response->setCache([
      'no_cache' => true,
      'max_age'  => 0,
      's_maxage' => 0,
    ]);

    return $response;
    
}
```

https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html#more-response-methods

Comment: The referenced article refers to using hinclude.js as opposed to ESI and the provided example insinuates cache-busting of the ESI style response provided by hinclude.js. The OP was wanting to implement real-time content updates like in [this recording](https://youtu.be/UI1l0JOjLeI). Can you explain how your answer achieves this?

Comment: They shared no code, and state "it's only onetime changing" so I assume they have reloaded the ESI and got the locally cached response. I did not watch the video so maybe I'm way off however, we should not have to view external media to obtain information that should be in the posted question (CRE). Also just because someone else believes what they assume the op is trying to do is impossible, is no reason not to try.

Comment: Despite the term "changing value on realtime" being used in the question title and text and being validated in the comments. Wouldn't it be more applicable to ask for clarifications and flag the question as "needs details or clarity"?